# Creating groups of data from raw data and plotting it?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create grouped data with the raw data I have, for my "age" variable. Age range of participants are from 12-66, however I was to group participants into the following as frequencies:

- 12-20
- 21-28
- 29-37
- 38-46
- 47-55
- 55-66

Also after Im trying to use this new grouped data and implement it into a histogram. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think that you need a barplot and not a histogram in your case.
With the help of akrun here is another possible solution. Thanks to akrun for his clarification (see comments):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
# random data of 1000 ages between 10 and 80 years
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(age = sample(10:80, 1000, replace = TRUE))

# dataframe with categorization of age in the suggested intervals. I think the last 55 is a typo.
df1 <- df %>% 
  mutate(agegroup = case_when(age >= 12  & age <= 20 ~ '12-20',
                              age >= 21  & age <= 28 ~ '21-28',
                              age >= 29  & age <= 37 ~ '29-37',
                              age >= 38  & age <= 46 ~ '38-46',
                              age >= 47  & age <= 55 ~ '47-55',
                              age >= 56  & age <= 66 ~ '56-66',
  )
  ) %>% 
  count(agegroup)

# plot the bars
ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=agegroup, y=n)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We could use `cut` to create the groups based on the `breaks`, get the count with `table` and plot with `barplot` in `base R`

```
grp <- cut(age, breaks = c(-Inf, 12, 21, 29, 38, 47, 55, 66, Inf))
barplot(table(grp))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
age <- sample(10:80, 1000, replace = TRUE)
```

Comment: Why does the output of `cut` comes in this format `(38,47]`. Why not just `(38,47)`

Comment: @TarJae It is just the way `cut` formats by default.  You can make it custom with `labels = c("(12,20)", ..., "(38,47)",...)`

Comment: @TarJae You can check the source code of `cut.default` `paste0(if (right) 
                "("
            else "[", ch.br[-nb], ",", ch.br[-1L], if (right) 
                "]"`

Comment: Thank you akrun. I was on the same way to suggest a similar answer to user15344033 but I stopped because of the breaks. If you look at the breaks each bar contains the last number of the bar before: so for example bar 2 contains 21 and bar 3 contains 21. Maybe I am wrong or I am overlooking something. Thank you anyway. Perfect as everytime!!

Comment: @TarJae The reason is that in `cut`, there are other arguments as well `include.lowest = FALSE, right = TRUE`.  You may need to change it.  I was just showing an option to group it.  The OP could make changes in the `cut` to make it custom

Comment: try ```labels=FALSE```